# What while populating list we find a column null

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am using this code to get data off data table,

```
List<CustomList> cls = new List<CustomList>();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS()))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, conn))
{
  conn.Open();

  using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
      CustomList cl = new CustomList();
      cl.FruitA = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["FruitA"]);
      cl.FruitB = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["FruitB"]);

      if (!Convert.IsDBNull(rdr["FruitCrateString"]))
        cd.FruitCrateString = rdr["FruitCrateString"].ToString();

      cls.add(cl); 
      //how can i skip above when  FruitCrateString is null and don't add rest to list
```

Now I know FruitA and FruitB will never be null but FruitCrateString can be null, but if fruitCrateString is null I want to skip the list instance, i know i can do this,

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
  if (!Convert.IsDBNull(rdr["FruitCrateString"]))
  {
    cl.FruitA = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["FruitA"]);
    cl.FruitB = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["FruitB"]);

    cd.FruitCrateString = rdr["FruitCrateString"].ToString();
}
```

but is there any better way of tackling this problem ?

Comment: I think your code is okay. Just instantiate `CustomList cl = new CustomList();` inside the `if (!Convert.IsDBNull(rdr["FruitCrateString"]))` block.

Comment: You could change your sql statement to exclude rows where FruitCrateString is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution that I know is to add the "IS NOT NULL" in the SQL select command. With it you can be sure that all the elements that you receive are good.

```
SELECT * FROM Fruits WHERE FruitA IS NOT NULL;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yup it helped but I also have a select statement calling for 6 or 7 columns, can i check all of them together if they are null or not, i will accept this answer anyway

Comment: I don't know if there is any sql statement to check all together, but you can check one by one if they are not null. SELECT * FROM Fruits WHERE FruitA IS NOT NULL AND FruitB IS NOT NULL;